# SQL Server "shortcut" processing

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

Here is a simplified version of the problem I'm trying to solve.

I have a temporary table `#MyData` with 2 columns: `description` and `value`.

I also have tables `MyRuleSequenceCollection`, `MyRuleSequence`, and `MyRule`, which I want to use to assess the data in the temporary table.  `MyRuleSequence` is an ordered list of `MyRule` records, and `MyRuleSequenceCollection` is an unordered collection of `MyRuleSequence` records.

One of the sequences looks for records in the temporary table with descriptions "A" and "B", then attempts to divide A by B.  The first rule tests for the presence of A, if it's not there, the process should stop.  The second rule tests for the presence of B, if it's not there, the process should stop.  The third rule tests that B is not 0, if it is 0, the process should stop.  Finally, the 4th rule divides A by B and tests whether the result is more than 1.

Temporary table contains:

```
A  20
B  5
```

Result: all 4 rules assessed, final result `true`

Temporary table contains:

```
A   20
B   0
```

Result: only first 3 rules run, no divide by 0 error, final result `false`

Temporary table contains:

```
B   20
C   5
```

Result: only first rule runs, final result false

The only way I can see to design this is either with cursors, or worse, with dynamic SQL.

So I'm looking for design suggestions.  Considering the above as just an example (many cases are far more complex), can this process be designed to avoid cursors or dynamic SQL?  Could recursion be a solution?

Update: several days with no suggestions or input.  Does anyone have an opinion about using CTE for this?  Or is that just a cursor with the deallocate handled for you?

Comment: First of all, Dynamic SQL is not evil.  Odds are I would choose dynamic over a cursor. Secondly, I would suggest editing your question and provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added a couple of examples.  The real problem is far more complex than this, but this should be enough to determine a paradigm.

Comment: Database tables exist to represent objects _outside_ of the database. In this case, a rule is something best materialized and executed by client code. Just write a query to return the rules in the proper order, and then let the client code decide how to evaluate them.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  I guess I should have mentioned that there is a strong preference for implementing this in SQL, so that it can be called from multiple platforms.  Also there are multiple reasons to skip to the next rule: variable not found so this rule doesn't apply, variable not found so this rule fails and no additional information is desired, or variable is outside the allowed range for some pending operation (e.g. negative number and next step will take square root, or zero and next step will use it as a divisor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, there really is no valid choice other than using a database cursor.

So that's what I've done.  It works, and performance and resource usage are reasonable.  It's a firehose forward only local static no locking everything else I could think of to speed it up cursor, and if I have performance problems later I can subset a couple of the joined/aliased tables (3 tables are left joined/aliased 10 times) into a table variable and use that in the cursor to speed it up further.

I'm left wondering why the automatic aversion to cursors is so strong, even in a case where there isn't a pragmatic alternative.